# Setting a background as a image url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern, swiper.js

I am creating a real estate app with the MERN stack as well as utilizing Swiper as a image slider and I am encountering a issue when trying to set the background of a div to images with a slider that was uploaded when creating a real estate listing. I am mapping through the array of images correctly however when attempting to set the background  I get nothing. Here is the snippet of the code that is not working.

```
    {listing && !loading && !error &&(
        <div>
            <Swiper navigation>
                {listing.imageUrls.map((url)=>(
                <SwiperSlide key={url}>
                <div
                    className='h-[550px]'
                    style={{
                    background: `url(${url}) center no-repeat`,
                    backgroundSize: 'cover',
                    }}
                ></div>
                </SwiperSlide>
                ))}
            </Swiper>
        </div>
)}
```

Comment: Hi, Did you try inspecting the elements?

Comment: Yes I am able to get the images by adding in a img tag with {url} as the src but I would like to set the images as the background for a better look. I am getting the images I want however setting them as the background has been troubling me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues could be happening so here are some potential solutions:

**Make sure background positioning and size is correct as it acts differently than `<img/>` (see snippet below)**

Replacing your div with these styles should help(making sure the background fills the div and adding height to div):

```
     <div
        className='h-[550px]'
        style={{
          backgroundImage: `url(${url})`,
          backgroundPosition: 'center',
          backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
          backgroundSize: 'cover',//adding size cover makes sure the image fills the entire div
          height: '550px !important', // must add base height if div is empty to still show background
        }}
      >
          Showing background for {url}
      </div>
```

### If you still have an issue

1. Make sure when you access the URL it is a path or URL to an **image ONLY**
2. If your URL array is an array of objects and not strings then you need to destructure the url from the object first such as `url.name` which you can debug with a console log like this:

```
    {
      listing.imageUrls.map((url) => {
        console.log('attempting to use url:', url)
        return (
        <SwiperSlide key={url}>
          <div
            className="h-[550px]"
            style={{
              background: `url(${url.name}) center no-repeat`,
              backgroundSize: "cover",
            }}
          ></div>
        </SwiperSlide>
      );});
    }
```

### Other Additions

Make sure your class h-[550] is not overriding any background or color styles (will cause background to not show)
I suggest creating a classname for this specific element and add it to css instead of inline css.

Answer (score 0):

I am following the same tutorial and was facing the same issue, using this worked for me:-

```
<div 
    className='h-[550px]'
    style={{
    background: `url('${url}')`,
    backgroundPosition: "center",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundSize: "cover",
}}></div>
```